# How to make Circular MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, swift, mpvolumeview

I'm trying to find a way around standard `MPVolumeView`.
I can customize slider min\max image, but is there a way to make it circular?
in swift, please

like this (but without number in the middle and border)?
[image]

Comment: Greag.deay can you explain what you want to do ?

Comment: @Shanmugasundharamselvadurai added picture, hope it is more clear now

Comment: @Gerag.Deay yeah i got it.